# Selectively outputting 2 inputs based on a third input

Tags: transistors, resistors, bjt, output, input

I currently have 2 inputs that can be on or off, they could be 00, 01, 10, or 11.  I want to output them only if a third input is active.  I figured BJT transistors would do the job, but they seem extremely finicky when it comes to linking their bases together, and though I have simulated a functional circuit using BJT transistors, I have not managed to build one.

Here is what I am trying to do:

[image]
<sub>(source: [hizliresim.com](https://i.hizliresim.com/O38XYA.png))</sub>

Here is my simplified simulation:

[image]
<sub>(source: [hizliresim.com](https://i.hizliresim.com/31W4rp.png))</sub>

Comment: And if the third input is inactive, what should it output?

Answer (score -1):

Well it turns out I was just using some penny transistors that weren't working properly.

Comment: Penny transistors are fine for this, provided that they're combined with other penny components.